# Historical Housing Data in Quandl

Tags: geospatial, api, real-estate

Quandl has [housing data through their API](https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-housing-data) including Price per square foot on the neighborhood level.  Is there a way to get the history for this data as well.  Say yearly back to 2009?